# Postgres: How can I join with an OR statement?

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.2

Given two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id INT4, "name" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE table2(table1_id INT4, name1 TEXT, name2 TEXT, name3 TEXT);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, "name") VALUES
(1, 'Jimmy'),
(2, 'John'),
(3, 'Sally'),
(4, 'Harry')
;

INSERT INTO table2 (name1, name2, name3) VALUES
('Jimmy', 'jim mcneil', 'James Mc''Neil'),
('Jonathon', 'Jon J.', 'Jon J. Jr.'),
('Sally S', 'Sally', 'Sally S. Smith'),
('Harry, Jr.', 'Harry H.', 'Harry')
;
```

how can I join where table1.name may equal any of the names in table2? Something to the effect of:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
FULL JOIN table2 b
 ON a."name" = b.name1 OR a."name" = b.name2 OR a."name" = b.name3
;
```

The `FULL JOIN` is (I think) important because I want to know (and see) both where there are matches and where there are not matches.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should work but this one is shorter:

```
on a."name" in (b.name1, b.name2, b.name3)
```

The `FULL join` will get no matches in both sides of the join. I suspect you want `left join` which will get no matches on the right side, that is, there will be nulls on the right side.

Comment: Thanks, but 'left join' only shows me where I'm missing data on the right side, not where data is missing from either the left or right and where they match as I would get with a 'full join'.